# Difference between system time and stored time

Tags: php

I created a simple form and I tried to store data and time (it was submitted). But it's not working. It has difference between my system time and stored time.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Colombo");

function setReviews($con) {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $email=$_POST["email"];
        $rating = $_POST["rating"];
        $review=$_POST["review"];
        $category_id=2;

        $sql="INSERT INTO review (category_id,email,rating,review,date,time) VALUES ('$category_id','$email','$rating','$review',CURDATE(),CURTIME())";

        if(!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Email already exists')</script>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Review submited')</script>";
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your issue? Does the Insert Query works but Insert the wrong Date ?

Answer (score 0):

CURDATE() AND CURTIME() are mysql functions and hence will take server time by default. You are setting the timezone in PHP using

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Colombo");
```

and hence you need to need to use:

```
date('Y-m-d') and date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

i.e PHP date function and not CURDATE() AND CURTIME()

Comment: My problem was this.. my system(pc) time is 8.17a.m. 14/08/2017. but i run insert data to my php form. it will stored 9.45.p.m. 14/08/2017. so can you give me solution.

Comment: And i have another question if i submit that form in sri lanka. it will be work correctly. but if i submit that in another country. it saved sri lanka time.. it not detect timezone correctly.